# create multiple client on apprtc

Tags: webrtc, apprtc, apprtcdemo

I am new in webrtc.I need to create a new implementation of webRtc. I got the source code of apprtc from Github. it is working fine on my local machine.

But in apprtc, it will support only maximum 2 clients(only one client can join to a single room). I need to modify the apprtc to support more than 2 clients. I want to join multiple clients to a single room. Is it possible with apprtc? if else, is any other way using webrtc?

Answer (score -1):

Try https://httprelay.io it allows one to many communication via ajax requests and requires no additional libraries.

Comment: i need webrtc implementation

Comment: Have you found the solution ?